# SQL: "Strict equals" doesn't work with LIKE % if last repeats a few times

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Among my DB columns there are the columns "tags" and "city". Because I need the search of exact words I'm using `LIKE %` a few times in the `WHERE` clause i.e.

```
SELECT ... WHERE `tags` LIKE '$keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords'"
```

It works good but if I added `AND city='".$city."'` to `WHERE` clause the SQL ignores this and I get all results for keywords (tags) even if I selected specific city that is no in any row of the DB column "city".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add round brackets around your or statements (problem of operator precedence)

```
where
(`tags` LIKE '$keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords'")
AND `city` = '".$city."'
```